# Why does Android Studio show import... vs. the actual import statements

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am new to Android development.

At various times I have noticed that the top of a Kotlin file shows `import...` and I have to click it each time to display the actual import directives.

What is that behavior?  Why do the import directives not just display each time I open the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're collapsed to reduce clutter so you can focus on the code itself. Most of the time there's no need to deal with the imports directly.

You can change this behavior in Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code folding. Disable "Imports" in the "General" section.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes sense. I was just not entirely sure if they were hiding it or if I was required to re-import it each time I loaded the file.